# Decoding issue while reading scraped csv files from memory

Tags: python, web-scraping, character-encoding, scrapy, decode

I have a web crawler made in scrapy that goes through webpages, downloads several CSV/TXT/ZIP files and parse the data in the files for scrapy items. Those files are not saved in disk, they remain in memory as I don't need them after parsing.

To be accurate, the files are either `.txt` or `.zip` with `.txt` inside them, however they are Comma-separated, so I deal with them as csv. Here is how it works:

```
import csv
import io
import zipfile

headers = ['list', 'of strings', 'with headers names']

def parse(self, response, ftype):
    if ftype == 'zip':
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.body))
        file = io.TextIOWrapper(zip_file.open(zip_file.namelist()[0]))
    else: #If file was .txt
        file = io.StringIO(response.text)

    reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=headers)
    for row in reader:
        yield self.parse_row(row)
```

All of the files successfully open, however some raise an `UnicodeDecodeError` **during the reader iteration**. (They read up to the line before the error - all issues are related to files originally `.zip`)

The excetion reads:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 7123: invalid start byte.
```

*[Also happening with byte 0x8a]*

I'm not sure what to do with it. Is there a way to read these files in a different encoding using `csv.DictReader` or `io`?

I'm looking for solutions that preferably don't involve third party dependencies (meaning, not included in Python standard libs), even if it means harder to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of the files in your zipfiles have an encoding other than UTF-8.  Here's a simplified example of what's happening.

```
>>> # Make a string of csv-like rows.
>>> rows = 'h1,h2\nhello,world\nßäæ,öë\n'
>>> # Encode the data with an encoding that isn't UTF-8
>>> # (cp1252 is common on Windows machines)  
>>> bs = rows.encode('cp1252')
>>> # Load the encoded bytes into a file-like object
>>> bio = io.BytesIO(bs)                  
>>> bio.seek(0)                          
0
>>> # Load the file-like object into a TextIOWrapper
>>> w = io.TextIOWrapper(bio)            
>>> w.seek(0)                            
0
>>> # Pass the TextIOWrapper to a csv reader and read it
>>> reader = csv.reader(w)               
>>> for row in reader:print(row)         
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kev/virtual-envs/so38/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 18: invalid continuation byte
```

The solution is to pass an `encoding` argument to `TextIOWrapper` so that the data is decoded correctly:

```
>>> bio = io.BytesIO(bs)
>>> bio.seek(0)
0
>>> # Tell TextIOWrapper these bytes are cp1252!
>>> w = io.TextIOWrapper(bio, encoding='cp1252')
>>> w.seek(0)
0
>>> reader = csv.reader(w)
>>> for row in reader:print(row)
... 
['h1', 'h2']
['hello', 'world']
['ßäæ', 'öë']
```

There is another problem though - you need to know which encoding to pass to `TextIOWrapper`.  Unfortunately there's no 100%-certain way to determine a file's encoding.  You may be able to guess (all these files come from Windows users in English-speaking<sup>*</sup> countries, so cp1252 is a likely solution), or you can use tools like [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) to guess for you.

<sup>*</sup> The [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) module in the standard library has a list of codecs available in Python and the human languages that they are related to.

Comment: Funny enough I just solved this issue 20mins ago. I didn't new ```TextIOWrapper``` taked an encoding parameter. Used ```chardet``` to find out what encoding it was. Thanks!